# Angular material multiple Select "window" width

Tags: angular-material

I Have simple multiple select:

```
  <button
    class="filter-icon-select ml-2"
    mat-icon-button
    matTooltip="Категории"
    (click)="selectCategories.open()"
  >
    <mat-icon [color]="service.filters.selectedCategories.length ? 'primary' : undefined">category</mat-icon>
    <mat-select #selectCategories [(ngModel)]="service.filters.selectedCategories" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let category of service.categories" [value]="category.id">
        {{category.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </button>
```

and got this:

[image]

my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "16.2.5",
        "@angular/cdk": "16.2.4",
        "@angular/common": "16.2.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "16.2.5",
        "@angular/core": "16.2.5",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "15.0.0-beta.42",
        "@angular/forms": "16.2.5",
        "@angular/material": "16.2.4",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "16.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "16.2.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.2.5",
        "@angular/router": "16.2.5",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.13.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.4.2",
        "jwt-decode": "3.1.2",
        "libphonenumber-js": "1.10.44",
        "moment": "2.29.4",
        "rxjs": "7.5.6",
        "tslib": "2.4.0",
        "zone.js": "0.13.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
            "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.2.2",
            "@angular/cli": "16.2.2",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.2.5",
            "@types/jasmine": "4.0.3",
            "@types/node": "18.7.2",
            "jasmine-core": "4.3.0",
            "karma": "6.4.0",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.1",
            "karma-coverage": "2.2.0",
            "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.0.0",
            "typescript": "4.9.5"
          }
```

problem somewhere in overlay with css property "width"...

Comment: if add [panelWidth]="null" to mat-select - all work normally, but it's a wreck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using a `mat-select` inside of a `button` tag.
This means that the `mat-select` will occuppy the width of its parent, the `<button>...</button>` by default.

You can manually set the panel width via the input `panelWidth`, according to the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api), like so:

```html
  <button
    class="filter-icon-select ml-2"
    mat-icon-button
    matTooltip="Категории"
    (click)="selectCategories.open()"
  >
    <mat-icon [color]="service.filters.selectedCategories.length ? 'primary' : undefined">category</mat-icon>
    <mat-select 
      #selectCategories
      [(ngModel)]="service.filters.selectedCategories"
      [panelWidth]='500px'
      multiple
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let category of service.categories" [value]="category.id">
        {{category.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </button>
```

Comment: if set null to panelWidth - width of select window will be normally calculated